# What if there is no match type?

Tags: scala

```
a match {
    case Some(myType) => {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Here is my some scala code and there is no

```
case None =>
case _ =>
```

line.

do I have to add these line for default? Or can skip them?

Comment: Adding a default case will help avoiding unexpected type exceptions.

Comment: It will throw an error if no match is found.

Comment: You only need to add `case _ =>` to add a default case. `case None =>` is explicitly matching against the `None` type; it is not a default statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a match {
  case Some(myVal) => // do something with myVal
}
```

This will compile with a warning...

> Warning: match may not be exhaustive.

...because the compiler knows that `a` could have a value that isn't covered, and if that happened then this code would throw a run-time error.

```
a match {
  case Some(myVal) => // do something with myVal
  case _ => // universal default; do something else
}
```

This compiles  without warning because it offers the universal default.

```
a match {
  case Some(myVal) => // do something with myVal
  case None => // do something else
}
```

This also compiles without warning because the compiler is smart enough to know that an `Option` can have only two states: `None` and `Some(value)`

NOTE: All of this only applies, of course, if `a` is an `Option[_]`. Otherwise `case Some()` and `case None` make no sense and won't compile.

Oh, and just to cover all the bases...

```
a match {
  case Some(myVal) => // do something with myVal
  case None => // do something else
  case _ => // redundant; unreachable code
}
```

Comment: If `a` is an `Option` you will get this warning because `Option` is a sealed type. If the type of `a` is not known or is a supertype of `Option` then the code will compile and you will not get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands the code will throw `MatchError` if `a` is not `Some[T]`. You can avoid this by adding a catch-all case

```
a match {
    case Some(myType) => {
        // do things
    }
    case _ =>
}
```

This will do nothing if `a` is `None` or is not an `Option` type. If you know that `a` is an `Option` then using `foreach` will do the same thing in a neater way

```
a.foreach { myType =>
    // do some things
}
```

**Note**

This will match any `Option` type. To pick a particular `Option` type you need to specify the inner type of the `Option`

```
a match {
    case Some(i: Int) =>
        // Do something with an int
    case Some(s: String) =>
        // Do something with a string
    case _ =>
        // Handle error condition
}
```